# How to apply node access rules when querying menu_links table

Tags: routes, database, security

I am creating a custom block which displays a menu.  The menu is constructed by retrieving certain menu links from the menu_links table in the database. It has occurred to me that building it this way could introduce a security issue, in the situation that a user does not have permission to view a certain node, but that menu link is still included in in the custom block.

I am wondering if there is some way of filtering results obtained from menu_links table based on current user role?

Menu links are currently being retrieved with queries like this one:

```
// Get all siblings of parent menu.
$siblings = db_select('menu_links', 'ml')
  ->fields('ml')
  ->condition('plid', $target['plid'])
  ->condition('hidden', 0)
  ->orderBy('weight')
  ->execute();
```

Actual menu structure is being constructed as a render array (basically each menu item is a link within a div wrapper).  Below is example of how a menu item is being constructed:

```
foreach ($siblings as $sibling) {
  $link = l($sibling->link_title, $sibling->link_path);
  $menu_item = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('nav-level0'),
    ),
    'content' => array(
      '#markup' => $link,
    ),
  );
  $menu[] = $menu_item;
}
```

Comment: If you somehow get the path from the links before you render them you could call drupal_valid_path($path) to check if the current user has access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`menu_get_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) will set return an `access` element that notes whether the current user has access.

```
  $siblings = db_select('menu_links', 'ml')
    ->fields('ml')
    ->condition('plid', $target['plid'])
    ->condition('hidden', 0)
    ->orderBy('weight')
    ->execute();
  foreach($siblings as $sibling) {
    $menu_item = menu_get_item($sibling->link_path);

    if($menu_item['access']) { 
      //Current user has access
    } else { 
      //Current user doesn't has access
    }
  }
```